# write a loop into html div with JS

Tags: javascript, loops, innerhtml

I don't understand why this code is not working, could you help me please ?
I want that when you click on the button, the "theloop" div get filled with yo 0 , yo 1 etc... till the number you inputed

```
<p>
    enter how many time you want the loop to repeat 
    <input id="nloop">
</p>
</br>

<button onclick="displayLoop()">
    Try it
</button>

<p id="theloop"></p>

<script>
    var nloop   = document.getElementById("nloop").value;
    var theloop = document.getElementById("theloop")

    function displayLoop () {
        for (var i=0; i<nloop; i++) {
            theloop.innerHTML = "yo" + i;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What isn't working? What should your code be doing, and what is it doing now? Please explain carefully

Comment: a closing bracket `}` is missing before `</script>`

Comment: there are also `()` missing after `displayLoop`

Comment: You have many Syntax Error, read how to write a function and a for loop,  () in your function declartion is missing, closing bracket in your for is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed few syntax checks that I have corrected:

```
<p>enter how many time you want the loop to repeat <input id="nloop" /></p>   

</br>

<button onclick="displayLoop();">Try it</button>

<p id="theloop"></p>

    <script>                  
        var theloop = document.getElementById("theloop");

        function displayLoop () {
            var nloop = document.getElementById("nloop").value;
            for (var i=0; i<nloop; i++)
             {
                theloop.innerHTML = "yo" + i;
             }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many Syntax error + code error

```
<p>enter how many time you want the loop to repeat <input id="nloop"></p>   </br>

<button onclick="displayLoop()">Try it</button>

<p id="theloop"></p>

<script>
    var theloop = document.getElementById("theloop")

    function displayLoop(){
        var nloop = document.getElementById("nloop").value;
        theloop.innerHTML = '';
        for (var i=0; i<nloop; i++){
            theloop.innerHTML = theloop.innerHTML + "yo" + i+ "<br/>";
        }
    }
</script>
```

You need to get the value of nloop when you call the function or the value will be the value when the script is loading, so an empty value.
If you affect something to innerHtml it will erase the content of the innerHtml.

I added BR only for the style you can ignore that.

Comment: I modified the answer and added theloop.innerHTML = ''; to re-initialise html content if you need. Thanks to accept the answer :)

Comment: You should modify your question tite on "With javascript", you're using javascript and not CSS, CSS is used to give style to your page. You are writing JS in your script tag ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   function displayLoop()
   {
        var nloop = document.getElementById("nloop").value;
        for (var i=0; i<nloop; i++)
        {
            document.getElementById("theloop").innerHTML += "yo" + i;
        }   
   }
</script>
```

This is working fine now :)